# What is the correct Content-Length to set for a GET request?

Tags: http, http-headers, httpwebrequest, content-length

When I make a `POST` request using the following code:

```
string body = "Hello World";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://internalurl");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
```

I set the content length to the number of bytes `POST`ed.
What is the correct `ContentLength` for a `GET` request?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since you normally doesn't send any additional data when you do a `GET` request, the header `Content-Length` should not be sent at all.

The header `Content-Length` should only be included when you are sending a *message-body*, and the value of the header in question is always the length of this field, measured in (*OCTETs*) bytes.

> ### [(RFC2616) 14.13 Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)
>
> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would have been sent had the request been a GET.
>
> <snip />
>
> Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the transfer-length of the message-body, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section [4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).

---

It's (AFAIK) considered bad practice to include a *message-body*  when doing a `GET` request, but when reading the HTTP [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) I see nothing stating that a `GET` request cannot include a *message-body*.

Though I will assume that most web servers today will not reply with what you want them to reply if you send data in a *message-body* and expects it to be parsed and handled in that case.

> ### [(RFC2616) 4.3 Message Body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3)
>
> The message-body (if any) of an HTTP message is used to carry the
>   entity-body associated with the request or response. The message-body
>   differs from the entity-body only when a transfer-coding has been
>   applied, as indicated by the Transfer-Encoding header field (section
>   14.41).
>
> ```
>    message-body = entity-body
>                 | <entity-body encoded as per Transfer-Encoding>
> ```
>
> Transfer-Encoding MUST be used to indicate any transfer-codings
>   applied by an application to ensure safe and proper transfer of the
>   message. Transfer-Encoding is a property of the message, not of the entity, and thus MAY be added or removed by any application along the
>   request/response chain. (However, section 3.6 places restrictions on
>   when certain transfer-codings may be used.)
>
> The rules for when a message-body is allowed in a message differ for
>   requests and responses.
>
> The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the
>   inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in the
>   request's message-headers.
>
> A message-body MUST NOT be included in a request if the specification of the request method (section 5.1.1) does not allow sending an entity-body in requests.
>
> A server SHOULD read and forward a message-body on any request; if the request method
>   does not include defined semantics for an entity-body, then the
>   message-body SHOULD be ignored when handling the request.

Comment: Small complement to this answer: [RFC7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) (part of the new RFC723x series of RFC that obsoletes the "old" RFC2616) simply says that `A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.`

Comment: @Filip If you have a json content in a String format, do you set the "Content-Length" as json.getBytes("UTF-8") ? I tried that and received Bad Request - Invalid Content Length
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. There is an invalid content length or chunk length in the request.</p>

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230 RFC7230 now explicitly says "A user agent SHOULD NOT send a
   Content-Length header field when the request message does not contain  a payload body and the method semantics do not anticipate such a  body."